# Deleting the records in the database (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to delete the record of a person entered in the textbox. This is the code I have and I don't know what to do next because my code is not working.

```
    AcademicAssessmentConnection = New OleDbConnection("provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;data source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\AdvisorAssessmentTool.accdb")

    AcademicAssessmentConnection.Open()

    AcademicAssessmentCommand = New OleDbCommand()
    AcademicAssessmentCommand.Connection = AcademicAssessmentConnection
    AcademicAssessmentCommand.CommandText = "DELETE (*) from Students where StudentID = @lookup"
    AcademicAssessmentCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("Successfully Deleted")
    AcademicAssessmentConnection.Close()
```

Comment: So what error do you get?  And presumably you have also provided a value for @lookup?

Comment: "DELETE from Students where..." not "DELETE (*) from Students where ..."  And you need to add a parameter for `@lookup`

Comment: @lookup is supposed to be the input from the textbox. How do I get the input from textbox to work in this kind of query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a parameter to the Command object that contains the value for @lookup.

```
AcademicAssessmentCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lookup", lookup);
```