# VB.NET: Checking the database to see if the data exists

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to check if the data for the id number entered in the text box exists in the database. If it does, I want my program to go another windowsform. If not, it should return error message. This is my code but it doesn't work. I would appreciate any help!

```
AcademicAssessmentCommand.CommandText = "Select StudentID from DarsReports WHERE StudentID = " &     StudentIDInMainTextBox.Text & ""

    Dim AATDataReader As OleDbDataReader = AcademicAssessmentCommand.ExecuteReader()

    If AATDataReader.Read() Then
        Dim searchForm As New SearchForm
        searchForm.ShowDialog()
    Else
        MsgBox("The Record does not exist in the database.")
    End If
```

Comment: a SQL DELETE query is not going to return a recordset to read; the [previous version of this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27010729/1070452) was in better form using Parameters

Comment: That was my bad. I meant to write Select

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.